# Highcharts: how to get the default export options on a chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts for my project. I use the following to hide the default dropdown for the export options of a chart:

```
$('#mycontainer").highcharts({
   ...
   chart: {
      type: 'column'
   },
   exporting: {
     enabled: false
   }
   ..
});
```

However, I do need these export options and I need to put them in my own menu together with other things. If I am right, the default export options on a single chart are basically Javascript-driven on the client side and has nothing to do with the server.

How can I rebuild these export options and put them in javascript?

**UPDATE**

exporting.js is already included in my page, but I want to disable the default export dropdown it generates and move the default dropdown export options into my own menu. I need to know what the default dropdown options links or javascript are so that I can make my menu work the same way the default export dropdown does.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you looking for **<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>**

Comment: Swetha, I know of this script. It is already included in my page. But I don't want the default export dropdown generated by exporting.js. I hope to put add the defaul export dropdown options into my own menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default export options are (directly from the [exporting.src.js](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.src.js)):

```js
menuItems: [{
    textKey: 'printChart',
    onclick: function () {
        this.print();
    }
}, {
    separator: true
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadPNG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart();
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/jpeg'
        });
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadPDF',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadSVG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/svg+xml'
        });
    }
}
// Enable this block to add "View SVG" to the dropdown menu
/*
,{

    text: 'View SVG',
    onclick: function () {
        var svg = this.getSVG()
            .replace(/</g, '\n&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

        doc.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + svg + '</pre>';
    }
} // */
]
```

Here `this` refers to the chart itself, so you could replace it with your `chart` variable.

For example with JPEG exporting:

```js
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.exportChart({
    type: 'image/jpeg'
});
```

Or see [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/8g17p5fj/).

Comment: Ondkloss, thanks so much for helping me. I tried chart.exportChart({
    type: 'image/jpeg'
}); directly after var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); I got javascript error: chartObject.exportChart is not a function

Comment: I also used setTimeout to call exportChart to make sure the chart object is fully constructed.      setTimeout(function(){
      chart.exportChart({
       type: 'image/jpeg'
   });     
     }, 3000);  I still got the same javascript error.

Comment: Oh, yes curious1. This still requires the `exporting.js` include, so you would have to just disable the button, as you've already done.

Comment: Ondkloss, I got the javascript error when I included exporting.js and disabled the button. Thanks!

Comment: Got the error? You mean fixed it? I also added a JSFiddle to the answer. Hope you solved your problem.

Comment: Ondkloss, thanks for the jsfiddle demo. After reading your code, I understand where I got wrong. I should have used var chart = $('#container').highcharts(). I got wrong because I used the chart object that was created when the graph is initialized. Thanks for your help!!!